# OpenCV Hog Detector - Debug Assertion Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

When I try to run an opencv code with a hog detector included, a get the following error.

Ive been using OpenCV for other things, and I've only gotten an error when including hog.

```
"Debug Assertion Failed"... Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)"
```

The code is the most simple one of hog I found from here: http://www.magicandlove.com/blog/2011/08/26/people-detection-in-opencv-again/

If I comment out this line it runs (just doesn't do the job obviously):

```
hog.setSVMDetector(cv::HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());
```

Comment: since `cv::HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector()` returns a std::vector, my first guess is, you got a problem with c-runtime libs, like the dll was linked against multithreaded-dll, and your prog is using another

Comment: Thanks berak, do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: hey, again, i'm just guessing here(might not be true even). just check if "c++" -> "code generation" is set to "multithreaded dll" in your proj.

Comment: Worked THANK YOU! Post it as an answer so I can accept :)

Comment: really, lucky dip ;) the more interesting question would be - what did you do to get something else there ? (since it seems to be the default, at least for an 'empty' project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your project will have to use the very same c-runtime libs, that the opencv dlls were compiled against.

so, set  "c++" -> "code generation" to "multithreaded dll" in your project.